# Pre commit hook solution

Tags: bash, git

I'm looking for a solution where before I push, it determines what host it's pushing to and then changes to the appropriate git user. For example if I'm pushing to a bitbucket then I should use

```
example@bitbucket.com
```

if pushing to git then I should use

```
example@github.com.
```

Links to similar solutions or just high level of the approach is fine. 
currently I have a `switch_user` bash script that I use to toggle between usernames, but I could forget this.

Comment: Is this the same project or is this different projects?

Comment: Also, are you talking about the email address in the commits?

Comment: different projects

Answer (score 0):

Following [github's help page](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git#setting-your-email-address-for-a-single-repository), you can set the email that you commit as in the git repository with `git config user.email "email@example.com"`. The lack of the `--global` flag makes it so that it only applies to this particular repository.

If you want to do this automatically for new projects you add, I recommend adding a git alias script to figure it out for you. Something like `git smart-clone` and `git smart-remote-add`.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out I could actually do a global hook

On your global `gitconfig` which can be found here

```
$ vi ~/.gitconfig
```

Edit the `core.hookspath`

```
hookspath=/path/to/git-hooks
```

Then I did something like this

```
#!/bin/sh

File=$PWD/.git/config

if grep -q github.com "$File"; then
    git config --global user.name "Foo Bar"
    git config --global user.email example@github.com
else
    git config --global user.name "Bar Foo"
    git config --global user.email example@bitbucket.com
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

git commit nom_rep
git push nom_rep or fichier // pour ajouter les fichier 
git status